# Read and write gpx file in android

Tags: android, gps, gpx

I'm finding the way to write and read file in android. I have to write the application which can write longitude and latitude to gpx file, then I must read longitude and latitude from gpx file to recreate the way of user. Anybody can tell me how I can do that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GPXParser](http://gpxparser.alternativevision.ro/pages/download.html) library.

Example of writing a GPX file

```
GPX gpx = new GPX();
GPXParser gpxParser = new GPXParser();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fullPath);
gpxParser.writeGPX(gpx, out);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

To read and write à gpx file you should only know the file structure see this link: fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPX_%28format_de_fichier%29

Here is a tutorial for reading gpx file : http://www.edumobile.org/android/get-location-from-gpx-file/

You may also use the gpxparser library : http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpxparser/

Comment: is any library to write GPX file in android.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a GPX parser library for that.

A well-maintained GPX reader-only:

https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser

A 5 years old (but working-well) GPX reader and writer:

https://github.com/FrancescoRigoni/Android_GPX

Both of them are based on [Topografix GPX 1.1.](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/) and can be accessible through public maven repositories.